# Excel sheets processing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, dataframe

I want to iterate over each sheet in excel file to apply some function on top of the data in each sheet and then get the output in a separate excel with all the processed sheets of the original excel file (i.e. not an inplace operation).

Example :

Input file "Myfile.xlsx" contains 3 sheets (names not known, could be anything)

Output file "Myfile_processed.xlsx" also contains 3 sheets with the same sheetname as above (but with processed data since we applied function on top of it)

I am able to iterate over the sheets in excel and treat each sheet as a dataframe to apply my function on top of it. But, post that I am not sure how to append that dataframe as a sheet in new excel, along with all the other sheets.

Any leads on this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling them Dataframes I'm guessing you're using pandas already. With that in mind it should be quite straight forward with the use of an `ExcelWriter`. Here's a code snippet where you take that initial file, read it, filter each Dataframe and ultimately write them into each sheet of the new file.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
   df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name)

   df1 = df[df['column'] == 'A']
   df2 = df[df['column'] == 'A']
   df3 = df[df['column'] == 'A']

   df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name+'_df1', index=False)
   df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name+'_df2', index=False)
   df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name+'_df3', index=False)

writer.save()
```